# Spartacus 'ErrorPageTemplate' class added to the app-root

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Since I upgraded to the last version of Spartacus 2.1, I've been experimenting this bug.

[image]

Randomly this class is added to the root component, making everything look twisted by adding unwanted CSS everywhere.
Sometimes it appears and then refreshing the page, is no more there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a ticket on our github? So we can follow up from there.

Comment: And are you using a specific CSS versions.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Comment: Thanks @tobi-or-not-tobi I'm doing the Github issue

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, very helpful, we're looking into it.